# Defining static value in array in angular

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I need to add some static data in angular 1.5 verson Controller like

$scope.restaurant.day[0].date =  Some Date;

$scope.restaurant.day[1].date =  Another Date;

but when I do so It shows error.

other feild for day object of restaurant array is dynamic

Comment: `$scope.restaurant.days = [{date: 'jj/mm/yyyy'}, {date: 'jj/mm/yyyy'}]`;

Comment: Thanks .. It works

Comment: As it seems to have solved your issue I've posted it as an answer, you can accept it if your problem is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define objects and then push them into your array.

For example:

```
$scope.restaurant.day = [];
day1 = {'date':'11/10/2016'};
$scope.restaurant.day.push(day1);
```